# K-means clustering doesn't find all clusters in data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

The set of data I am using is shown below. As one can see you would think the k-means cluster analysis would find the centers of these clusters easily.

[image: Initial Data]

However, when I run K-means cluster analysis and plot the centers I get this.

[image: K-means Cluster Centers]

I am using just the basic kmeans code:

```
cluster <- kmeans(mydata,90)
cluster$centers
```

Comment: Kmeans is not a deterministic algorithm, the randomness of initial centers will influence the final result.  If you have an expected result then predefine the initial centers or find a different algorithm.

Comment: It is approximately 5,000 data points. But they are arranged into structured clusters (approximately 40-60 data points per cluster).

Comment: Have you tried using another clustering algorithm to find the centers, and then send the centers to k-means? [e.g. h-clust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547697/cluster-algorithm-with-levenshtein-distance-and-additional-features-variables/44551452#44551452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, using `hclust()` to find the centers might be a viable approach.

[image]

```
set.seed(1)

l <- 1e4
v1 <- sample(1:10, l, replace=TRUE) + rnorm(l, 0, 0.05)
v2 <- sample(1:13, l, replace=TRUE) + rnorm(l, 0, 0.05)
dtf <- data.frame(v1, v2)

par(mar=c(2, 2, 1, 1))
plot(dtf, pch=16, cex=0.2, col="#00000044")

km <- kmeans(dtf, 10*13)
points(km$centers, cex=2, lwd=0.5, col="red")

hc <- hclust(dist(dtf))
hc <- cutree(hc, 10*13)
hcent <- aggregate(dtf, list(hc), mean)[, -1]

hckm <- kmeans(dtf, hcent)

points(hckm$centers, cex=3, lwd=0.5, col="blue")
```

Answer (score 2):

A little-known fact about kmeans is that to get reliable results, you need to run the algorithm repeatedly with many random initializations. I typically use `kmeans(, nstart = 1000)`.

In theory, the `kmeans++` algorithm does not suffer as much from the initialization problem, but I often find that `kmeans` with many random restarts performs better than `kmeans++`. Still, you might want to try `kmeans++` using the `flexclust` R package.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem I was having. It did improve the results slightly but I am still getting overlapping cluster centers.

Comment: Try going up to `nstart = 10000` or even `nstart = 100000`. If neither of those works then you'll need some other way of coming up with a good initialization. Not a very satisfying answer, I know, but optimal k-means clustering is an NP-complete problem so there's not much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This data set is likely to be much better to be clustered by DBSCAN.

Choose epsilon less than the distance of clusters (e.g., 10), and Minpts should not matter much then, e.g., minpts=4

Comment: This seems to give me the 90 clusters I am looking for but how do I extract the center/mean of each cluster?

Comment: DBSCAN is not center based, bug you can easily compute the mean yourself.